# Python: Why is so difficult to convert an array into a unique string with new lines as separator?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have an array like this:

```
names = [ 'John', 'Mary', 'Mike' ]
```

I need to instantiate a new string, with each name separated by a new line `\n`

I've already tried `joined_string = '\n'.join(names)` but with no succes.
Another try was using F-String (or even normal string concatenation with `+` or `"%s\n" % (name)`

```py
joined_string = ""
for name in names:
    joined_string += f"{name}\n"
```

All my tests, always give an output like this

```
John\nMary\nMike
```

The desired output is a new string like this:

```
joined_string = '''John
Mary
Mike
'''
```

**I need the content to be in a variable**, without using `print` statement.

**EDIT**: The actual code I'm running in Python 3.6

```
names = ['John', 'Mary', 'Mike']
joined_string = '\n'.join(names)
print(joined_string)
```

Console output gives:
`John\nMary\nMike`

Expected output:

```
John
Mary
Mike
```

I know it seems weird, but my Python 3.6 is giving that output.

For those who don't believe it :

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what `'\n'.join(names)` does. You are confusing the string representation of a string with the string itself.

Comment: Instead of just typing `joined_string` at the interactive prompt, type `print(joined_string)`.

Comment: If you need a trailing newline (as in `joined_string` in your for-loop and `'''` examples), you can just use `f"{'\n'.join(names)}\n"` or `'\n'.join(names) + '\n'` or any other preferred string concatenation method.

Comment: Are you specifically asking for having a trailing newline? That's what your for loop and ``'''`` literal do, but not the ``join``.

Comment: It really helps to post the failing script so we can comment on changes.

Comment: @chepner I need to store the contente into a new string. I will not output the content using `print` statement.

Comment: Can you please clarify your desired output? What you are showing is an assignment *statement*, not some value nor its representation.

Comment: It *is* in the string. I'm telling you that using `print` will show you that your string *is* exactly what you want. (Whether you want a trailing newline as well is still unclear.) You aren't using `print` to *define* the variable.

Comment: `"John\nMary\nMike"` is exactly the same as your triple quoted string (minus the last, probably unintended newline). That's just two different ways to create the string in source code. Print both and see how they are the same.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Python outputs literal \n string not a new line string (char 13).

Comment: ``\n`` *is* a newline character.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I need a string variable with names separated into new line. But when I output the string, it gives me a literal \n output, not a <ENTER> (13 character).

Comment: @shimatai Quite plainly, you're misinterpreting it. Have you tried checking the length of the string, or the value of `ord` at each position to check that?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi but why it's printing literal \n instead of \U13 ?

Comment: @shimatai What you call "<ENTER>" is what python calls ``\n``.

Comment: @shimatai - then show us how you output the string. You are showing us the literal string representation of the string.

Comment: @Brian yes, it outputs \n not \u13 character. Name "John" + \n it should give 4 characters, but for me is giving 6 chars.

Comment: @shimatai `13` is a carriage return (spelled `\r` in Python). A newline as an ASCII value of `10`.

Comment: @shimatai You didn't **print** the string, as in `print(your_string)`.

Comment: @Brian I know that... and that's why I've asked the difficult behind this! In any other language, live JavaScript, Java, PHP if I concatenate "Mike" + '\n', it will give me the desired result. In my Python 3.6 is giving "Mike\n"

Comment: @ThierryLathuille but I don't wanna print the string! That's the point. I need to store in a variable the content separated by new line `\n`

Comment: As all comments already told you, that's **exactly** what you already have.

Comment: @shimatai The point is that you already *have* the string. Note for example that ``len("Mike\n")`` is 5 as desired. You need ``print`` if you want to *display* it properly *to yourself* since you are apparently not familiar with [Python's escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi but I don't wanna print. I need to store in memory to pass forward that string. But the receiver in the other method receives it with literal \n and not a new line character. If I print the string, it gives me `John\nMary\nMike` and not `John
Mary
Mike`

Comment: If "the receiver in the other method receives it with literal \n and not a new line character" then you should ask us about the receiver, because apparently there is something going wrong. A proper [mcve] using *literal* syntax for what you get and want would be useful...

Comment: @shimatai Can you [edit] you question to include an example that produces the string `r"John\nMary\nMike"`? Try typing `[ord(c) for c in '\n'.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])]`. Do you `10` for `\n`, or subsequences of `92, 110` for the two characters `'\'` and `'n'`?

Comment: @Brian nice suggestion! I will do it.

Comment: How and where are you running this? What you are showing looks more like an issue with the terminal emulator you are using than your Python code.

Comment: @chepner I think it's my installation or some weird setting in Python. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @chepner please, sse the picture added to the question

Comment: What terminal is that?

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the string representation of a string with the string itself.

```
>>> str1 = "\n".join(["John", "Mary", "Mike"])
>>> str2 = """John
... Mary
... Mike"""
>>> str1 == str2
True
```

When you use

```
>>> "\n".join(["John", "Mary", "Mike"])
'John\nMary\nMike'
```

you are seeing Python's representation of a `str` value: the quotes delimit, but are not part of, the string, and `\n` is just the visual representation that `str.__repr__` uses to show the linefeed character. When you use

```
>>> print("\n".join(["John", "Mary", "Mike"]))
John
Mary
Mike
```

you aren't changing the *value* with `print`, you are only writing each character to the terminal, which "displays" a line-feed by moving the cursor to the beginning of the next line rather than displaying any particular visible character.

Comment: When I use `print(str1)`, it prints "John\nMary\Mike" and not as you've shown, with line feed.

Comment: @shimatai Just to be clear: When you are running the code exactly as shown, i.e. just the single command ``print("\n".join(["John", "Mary", "Mike"]))``, the output is ``John\nMary\nMike``? Are there leading/trailing quotes in the output?

Comment: The output is `John\nMary\nMike` just like this! The code is very very simple. That's why I have to question. It's something too trivial! I don't know it is a problem in my Python installation or something else. I've coded the simplest code ever.

Comment: Does `str1 == str2` evaluate `True` for you? The *code* should be fine; this appears to be a problem with whatever terminal or console you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the literal string representation python uses to display strings. In fact, it is the string you want. When we create the joined string, python's "repr" represenation is

```
>>> names = [ 'John', 'Mary', 'Mike' ]
>>> joined_string = "\n".join(names)
>>> joined_string
'John\nMary\nMike'
```

But if we actuallly print the string, we get the "str" view

```
>>> print(joined_string)
John
Mary
Mike
```

Which is what you want.

From [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) *The backslash () character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.*. Using `"\n"` to denote the newline character `0x0a` when entering string literals in source code is common - C/C++ and many other languages do the same thing.

Comment: I know that. But if I use `print(joined_string)` it's printing `John\nMary\Mike` and not the output shown by you.

Comment: It's printing the literal \n and not the line feed character \u10 + \u13 or just \u13.

Comment: @shimatai - Dude. Don't just dribble hints around. This is the first time you've mentioned you are doing `print`. Just post a script showing the problem. Are you doing something different than what I demonstrated?

Comment: No. I've edit my question. It's as simple as you've coded.

Comment: Your script prints 3 lines in my terminal, no "\n". What console are you using?

Comment: Please, sse the picture added to the question

Comment: It doesn't do that in my console, which one are you using?